# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (13159,3) (13159,)

Tags: linear-regression, predict

I am trying to predict the target variable and finding the difference from actual variable using polynomial regression. However predicted variable is an array of 3 dimension with the shape as (13159,3) and actual targetvariable is of size (13159,). How can I get the compatible target variable to get the difference from predicted and actual variable. Below is the code snippet.

```py
polynomial_features= PolynomialFeatures(degree=1)
x_poly = polynomial_features.fit_transform(X_train)
y_poly = polynomial_features.fit_transform(y_train)
x_poly_test = polynomial_features.fit_transform(X_test)
y_poly_test = polynomial_features.fit_transform(y_test)


model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(x_poly, y_poly)
r_sq = model.score(x_poly_test, y_poly_test)

y_predict= model.predict(x_poly_test)

y_actual=y_test["Target variable"].to_numpy()

diff_value= y_predict - y_actual
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[32], line 1
----> 1 diff_value= y_predict - y_actual

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (13159,3) (13159,)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue in this code is that PolynomialFeatures transformation is being applied to the target variable y_train and y_test. This is not correct because PolynomialFeatures is used for feature expansion, it should only be applied on the features (X_train and X_test) not on the target variable.

Also, when you are using LinearRegression model's fit method, it expects 2D array-like for X_train and 1D array-like for y_train. But here, since you have transformed y_train into polynomial features which makes it a 2D array, this will cause an error.

Try the following:

```py
polynomial_features= PolynomialFeatures(degree=1)
x_poly = polynomial_features.fit_transform(X_train)
x_poly_test = polynomial_features.transform(X_test)

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(x_poly, y_train)
r_sq = model.score(x_poly_test, y_test)

y_predict= model.predict(x_poly_test)

y_actual=y_test["Target variable"].to_numpy()

diff_value= y_predict - y_actual
```